# How to change theorem numbering style in one chapter only?

Tags: numbering, theorems

I want to change numbering `theormn` and `lemma` in one chapter in thesis without change other chapters. Namely numbering (`theormn` and `lemma`) in one chapter is different from another chapter.

How to apply a change to one chapter only?

For example, in chapter 1,2,4,5:

```
\theoremstyle{definition}‎
‎‎\theoremstyle{theorem}‎
‎\newtheorem{theorem}{theormn}[chapter]‎
‎\newtheorem{lem}{lemma}‎
‎\newtheorem{cor}{corollary}‎
```

while in chapter 3:

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{theormn}‎
‎\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{lemma}‎
‎‎\newtheorem{colo}[theorem]{corollary}‎
```

‎

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Which document class do you use? Do you use any packages, such as `amsthm`, `ntheorem`, and `thmtools`, that set up macros such as `\theoremstyle`?

Answer (score 6):

You can define two sets of theorems, which is not a big deal, then define a pair of switching macros.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}

% normal theorems
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}

% special theorems
\newtheorem{Xtheorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{Xlem}[Xtheorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{Xcor}[Xtheorem]{Corollary}

\makeatletter
% add the theorem names you want to the following list
\newcommand{\tahora@theoremlist}{theorem,lem,cor}

% syntactic sugar; etoolbox already provides \csletcs, so \providecommand is used
\providecommand{\csletcs}[2]{%
  \expandafter\let\csname#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname#2\endcsname
}

% save the old meanings
\@for\next:=\tahora@theoremlist\do{%
  \global\csletcs{SAVED\next}{\next}%
  \global\csletcs{endSAVED\next}{end\next}%
}

% define the switching macros
\newcommand{\dospecialtheorems}{%
  \@for\next:=\tahora@theoremlist\do{%
    % change the meanings
    \global\csletcs{\next}{X\next}%
    \global\csletcs{end\next}{endX\next}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\undospecialtheorems}{%
  \@for\next:=\tahora@theoremlist\do{%
    % restore the meanings
    \global\csletcs{\next}{SAVED\next}%
    \global\csletcs{end\next}{endSAVED\next}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{One}

\begin{lem}
A lemma
\end{lem}

\begin{theorem}
A theorem
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
Another theorem
\end{theorem}

\begin{cor}
A corollary
\end{cor}

\chapter{Two}
% Switch to the special numbering
\dospecialtheorems

\begin{lem}
A lemma
\end{lem}

\begin{theorem}
A theorem
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
Another theorem
\end{theorem}

\begin{cor}
A corollary
\end{cor}

% Switch back to the usual numbering
\undospecialtheorems

\chapter{Three}

\begin{lem}
A lemma
\end{lem}

\begin{theorem}
A theorem
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
Another theorem
\end{theorem}

\begin{cor}
A corollary
\end{cor}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm not sure this is a good idea, though. Also I dislike having theorem statements in upright type: printing them in italics help readers giving them visual clues.