# Changing Theorem Numbering Format in Different Sections

Tags: numbering

It took me a little while to determine the following, but I think it's helpful and should be easily available, so I'm posting an "answer your own question" here. The question is this.

> How do I label theorems in a different format in different sections, eg **Theorem 1.1** and **Theorem 3.2.2**?

I had theorems label under section, 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, ..., ie under `\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]`. For *just Section 3* I wanted them to be labelled under subsection, 3.1.1, 3.1.2, 3.2.1, ..., ie under `\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[subsection]`.

Comment: Please phrase this as a question: how do I ....

Comment: You can create a community wiki which is exactly what you are trying to accomplish!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two relevant SE questions, [[1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155869/how-to-change-theorem-numbering-style-in-one-chapter-only),[2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194821/change-numbering-level-for-one-chapter-only)]. However, these, to me, seemed fairly complicated and there was a lot of stuff I didn't understand in them. (I expect the same holds for most TeX users.) By inspecting the answers, I found that the following works (and is simple).

Put `\usepackage{chngcntr}` in the preamble. Then, when you want to change the numbering style (so at the start of S3 in my example above), I put `\counterwithin{thm}{subsection}` at the start of the section. This makes the counter reset with subsections. At the start of the next section, I then put `\counterwithout{thm}{subsection} \counterwithin{thm}{section}`. This stops the counter from reseting with subsections, and makes it reset with the section.

This worked perfectly for me. Thank you in particular to Christian Hupfer, and [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/396464/81928).

Hopefully this will be helpful for someone!

Comment: If you want this to be helpful for others then please post a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). This should be a minimal piece of code that compiles and solves the problem.